# using binary file for complex object C++

Tags: c++

i have virtual base class named widget that have some derived classes. i wrote code to print it out to the screen:

```
std::ostream&  operator << (std::ostream& os, const Base& base) //output
    {
        os << . . . . //some orders for priting the base members
        Derived1* l = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(base);
        Derived2* d = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(base);
        Derived3* r = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(base);
        if (c != NULL)
        {
            os << ... / / some ostream orders 
        }

        else if (l != NULL)
        {
                        os << ... / / some ostream orders 

        }

        else if (r != NULL)
        {
            // some orders
        }

        return os;
    }
```

now, i am suppose to use it for writing\reading to\from binary file. is there ant option to do it?
some of the members - are dynimaclly alocated (strings, vectors, vector of pointers, etc.).
thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to use an existing [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) library (like [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)) then you could do it by first storing the size of the data followed by the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework question, so I won't give any code, but will try to point you in the right direction.

How are C-strings stored in an array? How do you know where the end of the array is?
 - Think about this.  In a C-string, there is a terminating character (`'/0'`) that signals the end of the string.  Maybe you could write a terminating character after each bit of data? Maybe something like `0xFF` as `0` could be valid data in your case.

Alternatively, add some meta-data to your file.  e.g. for each vector, precede it with the information of how many bytes for each member, and how many members:

e.g.

```
int = 5          ->  0x01 0x02 0x05            //one,   two byte value,  value  = 5.
int[3] = {5,6,7} ->  0x03 0x02 0x05 0x06 0x07  //three, two byte values, values = 5. 6 and 7.
```

Then your parsing program just needs to make sure it reads the right amount of data in each time.

To add in the different data-types, consider an enumeration of all the types to be stored.  Store the associated value with the data. This would allow you to efficently specify strings etc.